# Parse SendGrid JSON with PHP

Tags: php, json

I have some simple JSON data returned by the SendGrid API:

```
{  
   "message":"error",
   "errors":[  
      "some errors"
   ]
}
```

I can access the contents of the "message" section via:

```
$txt = "{\"message\":\"success\"}";
$newtxt = json_decode($txt, true);
echo $newtxt['message'];
```

That works okay, but I can't work out how to access the contents of the "errors" section?

Sorry, I realise this is probably a silly question.

Comment: Check some basic JSON + PHP guides; there are plenty of them out there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your JSON String is this

```
$tst = '{  
   "message":"error",
   "errors":[  
      "some errors"
   ]
}';
```

Then all you need to so is

```
$j_array = json_decode($txt, true);
echo $j_array['message'];
echo $j_array['errors'][0];
```

A better way would be to loop over this array

```
foreach ($j_array['errors'] as $error ) {
    echo $error . '<br>';
}
```

Of course you dont need to convert everything to an array, you can leave it as written i.e. an object containing properties one of which is an array

```
$jObj = json_decode($txt);
echo $jObj->message;
echo $jObj->errors[0];
```

Or

```
foreach ($jObj->errors as $error ) {
    echo $error . '<br>';
}
```